# main.cpp:16:60: error: expected ':' before 'O'

Tags: c++

I'm using conditional operator in line 16, but I don't what mistake I made in line 16.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    
   int num1{};
   
   cout << "Enter the mark you got:  ";
   cin >> num1;
   
   if(num1 >= 0 && num1 <= 100){
       char grade{};
       cout << "Nice work!, you got "<< ((num1 >= 90)?grade'O':grade'o') << " grade!" << endl;
   }else{
       cout << "Value is out of range!" << endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

To find the mistake I made

Comment: what do you think `((num1 >= 90)?grade'O':grade'o')` will evaluate to when `num1 = 91` ?

Comment: `<< grade << (num >= 90 ? 'O' : 'o') <<`

Comment: `grade'O'` doesn't look like something that makes sense in C++. Where did you find this construct?

Comment: "Nice work!, you got  O  grade!" that's the output I expected.

Comment: There has obviously been some kind of misunderstanding, but it's hard to say what or where it might have been.

Comment: Thanks "n. m. could be an AI" I edited my code after your comment,

Comment: cout << "Nice work!, you got "<< ((num1 >= 90)? grade='O':grade='o') << " grade!" << endl; And the output is like I expected "Enter the mark you got:  95
Nice work!, you got O grade!" Thanks man

Comment: And Joop Eggen yours too works perfectly

Comment: That statement doesn't make sense. Assignment first, as a separate statement. Then print it, separate statement. Or just don't use the variable `grade` at all, there's just no need for it. What is your actual assignment / exercise? Why do you need the `grade` variable?

Comment: @JoopEggen Not with the current code as shown in the question. `grade` is zero, there's nothing to print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible solutions:

1. Don't use the `grade` variable, it's really not needed:

   ```
   std::cout << "Nice work!, you got " << (num1 >= 90 ? 'O' : 'o') << " grade!\n";
   ```
2. Or if the variable is a requirement of the assignment / exercise, set its value in the initialization, and just print the variable value:

   ```
   char grade = num1 >= 90 ? 'O' : 'o';
   std::cout << "Nice work!, you got " << grade << " grade!\n";
   ```

Most importantly, don't try to do too much at once. Separate your statements, assignments, and expressions to make them easier to read, understand and maintain. And if a variable isn't needed, just skip it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this , I understand clearly now.

Comment: I like #2.  To my eyes, it's much easier to read.